# ERROR: Bad state: Can't create both a dart file edit and a generic file edit for the same file

Tags: flutter, dart

When running `dart fix --apply` I'm getting an error saying: `Bad state: Can't create both a dart file edit and a generic file edit for the same file`

What can this issue be?

Stack trace:

```
#0      ChangeBuilderImpl.addGenericFileEdit (package:analyzer_plugin/src/utilities/change_builder/change_builder_core.dart:166:7)
#1      ConvertDocumentationIntoLine.compute (package:analysis_server/src/services/correction/dart/convert_documentation_into_line.dart:81:19)
#2      BulkFixProcessor._applyProducer (package:analysis_server/src/services/correction/bulk_fix_processor.dart:297:22)
#3      BulkFixProcessor._generateFix (package:analysis_server/src/services/correction/bulk_fix_processor.dart:734:11)
#4      BulkFixProcessor._bulkApply (package:analysis_server/src/services/correction/bulk_fix_processor.dart:313:15)
#5      BulkFixProcessor._fixSingleError (package:analysis_server/src/services/correction/bulk_fix_processor.dart:618:15)
#6      BulkFixProcessor._fixErrorsInLibrary (package:analysis_server/src/services/correction/bulk_fix_processor.dart:521:15)
```

Comment: Could you share the code, please?

Comment: Could you share full stack trace

Answer (score 0):

The Dart Analyzer is unable to fix certain issues automatically. Please review your code manually to identify and correct any possible issues, and then run the command again.

Please note the following text: "nbsp" may appear in some strings. Check for this text and replace it accordingly.
For example: [image]

Also, check the rule set in the `analysis_options.yaml` file
See rules here: https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules